# dplyr mutate: Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'Name' given input columns

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr, regexp-replace

## Issue with sparklyr

I'm working on a project that needs a huge number of mutation for the cleansing and transformation phases using
**mutate** and **regexp_replace** functions
But what I see, there is a limitation for using mutate, in the below example If you reduce the number of mutate function, the example will work fine, but if you keep it as is, you will get the following error
`dplyr mutate: Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'Name' given input columns:`
So, What is the best practice to solve this?

---

My reproducible example:

```r
conf <- spark_config()

conf$spark.driver.cores <- 2
conf$spark.executor.memory <- "8G"
conf$spark.executor.cores <- 2
conf$spark.executor.instances <- 4
conf$spark.submit.deployMode    <- "client"
conf$spark.sql.catalogImplementation <- "hive"
conf$spark.driver.memory <- "8G"
conf$spark.driver.memoryOverhead <- "8G"
conf$spark.executor.memoryOverhead <- "8G"
conf$spark.rpc.message.maxSize <- 2047

conf$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "4G"
conf$`sparklyr.shell.executor-memory` <- "4G"
conf$`spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` <- "4G"

sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", 
                    config = conf)

tit <- copy_to(sc, titanic::titanic_test)
sdf_copy_to(sc, tit, overwrite = T)

pipeline <- . %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) %>% 
  mutate(Name = regexp_replace(Name, 'ma', 'Maher')) 

pipeline(tit)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, why are you repeating the mutate call more than once?

Comment: It's only example dear, in fact, I have the same number of mutation but with different expression and fields